# How can I make my checkboxes align in a form?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a question.. I have a div with 3 checkboxes and a textfield, so a form basically. The form is centered but now the checkboxes all align in the centre as well, and it does not look good. Does anyone know, how I can make them below each other?

```html
<div class="forms" align=center>
  <form action="/sendmail.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="xy" value="xy"> xy </p>    
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="zy" value="zy"> zy </p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="XS" value="XS"> XS </p>  
    <p>Extra: <textarea name="extra" cols="30" rows="7" wrap="wrap"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="reset">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: insert css pls!

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov in this case, css doesnt matter at all. he uses an inline styling. Would be betetr to actually read and understand the question aswell as the code befor asking for something that is not needed.

Comment: @tacoshy, i always read a question before giving an answer or comment. It is not a problem to give an answer on this question, but the author may have his own set of css rules that can interrupt the solution that I gave :). Therefore, I asked for css.

Comment: @tacoshy here is my css h2 {
    color:#585858;
    
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
        
    
        .header {
            background-color: #0068a5;
            padding-bottom: 1.5%;
            padding-left: 1.5%;
            padding-right: 1.5%;
            padding-top: 1.5%;
            
        }   
        
        p {
             font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        }
        
        b {color:#585858;
    
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
        }

Answer (score 1):

wrap the checkboxes in a div. In my snippet sample they a wrapped inside a div with the class `.wrapper`.
Then I use CSS attribute `width: min-content;`to make the width of that div only as wide as the largest content line. However this will cause an unwanted wordbreak behavior that is fixed with `white-space: nowrap;`.
last but not least, I give it a `text-align: left;` as the checkboxes are at the left side. That way they align below each other as they are aligned to the left side of the div.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="forms" align=center>
  <form action="/sendmail.php" method="post">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="xy" value="xy"> xy </p>    
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="zy" value="zy"> zy </p>
      <p><input type="checkbox" name="XS" value="XS"> XS </p>
    </div>
    <p>Extra: <textarea name="extra" cols="30" rows="7" wrap="wrap"></textarea></p>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="reset">
  </form>
</div>
```